# Django saying that table does not exist

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am working in a project which is using a mysql DB.
They imported the DB to Django models and it seemed that it wasn't missing anything. When I did a query with Django, though, it was saying a table was missing. I checked the table name in the DB and it was matching. Pretty weird. I solved the problem anyway by using the syntax ".using('db_config').values('column1', 'column2')"

The model was the following:

```
class UserRoles(models.Model):
    role_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_roles'
```

The command giving the error:

```
UserRoles.objects.filter(role_id=number)
```

The command without throwing the error:

```
r = UserRoles.objects.using('db_config').values('role_id')
q = r.filter(role_id=number)
```

The error was the following:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: user_roles
```

**My question here is why did Django could not find the table before? Why did I need to use the method "values"  to find the rows?**? I checked and all the fields were matching.I also ran makemigrations, syncdb before

PS: Another odd thing that it was that the metatag "unique_together" didn't work as well. I had to use the method "values" to make the query work as well. I don't know if it s related somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `values`, You're using the [`using`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.using) method in the second query which is used to tell django which database you want to query.

Henceforth you're looking in a separate database which does have the relevant migrations applied

Comment: That's true. Thanks! I feel a little embarrassed that I didn't see that... I checked and I have to use the method .all() after the "using" method.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this when they Google it, the problem that I had that caused this same error (which was not the OP's problem, as it turns out) was that I had a router that assigned the model to different hosts for reading and writing, and the writing host was behind a firewall, so that would be another thing to check if you see that Django is saying the table does not exist when it definitely does.